# How to set VMWare VM screen resolution on Windows using Ansible

Tags: windows, powershell, ansible, vmware-vsphere

I'm trying to deploy a vSphere Windows VM via Ansible and need to set a specific screen resolution (1024x768). Running [`VMWareResolutionSet.exe`](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2058577) works locally in PowerShell with the following command (the `,` needs to be escaped with a ` in Powershell to avoid making the arguments a list, and the `&` is needed to run commands with spaces in their paths):

```
& "C:\Program Files\VMWare\VMware Tools\VMwareResolutionSet.exe" 0 1 `, 0 0 1024 768
```

However, running this command remotely with Ansible's [`win_command`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_command_module.html) only yields a return code of `1` with no further error message. The same behavior occurs when running the command directly with [`pywinrm`](https://github.com/diyan/pywinrm) or when invoking PowerShell as a subshell. As far as I can tell, the problem lies with this not being an interactive PowerShell instance. However, setting `become: true` and `become_method: runas` did not work.

How can I set the VM screen resolution via Ansible?

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately I was unable to get this to run remotely via PowerShell, but I *was* able to run this as a scheduled task which runs immediately upon being registered:

```yaml
- name: Ensure that the user can run scheduled tasks
  win_user_right:
    name: "SeBatchLogonRight"
    action: add
    users:
      - "{{ ansible_user }}"

# Deleting and reregistering will force the task to run every time
- name: Remove screen resolution task if present
  win_scheduled_task:
    name: SetScreenResolution
    state: absent

- name: Create a task to set screen resolution
  win_scheduled_task:
    name: SetScreenResolution
    description: Set the screen resolution
    actions:
      - path: C:\Program Files\VMWare\VMware Tools\VMwareResolutionSet.exe
        arguments: "0 1 , 0 0 1024 768"
    triggers:
      - type: registration
    state: present
    enabled: true

- name: Wait for the scheduled task to complete
  win_scheduled_task_stat:
    name: SetScreenResolution
  register: task_stat
  until: (task_stat.state is defined and task_stat.state.status != "TASK_STATE_RUNNING") or (task_stat.task_exists == False)
  retries: 5
```

you can configure this task to delete itself using the instructions found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64006824/ansible-win-scheduled-task-how-to-start-a-task-immediately. I still suspect there's a way to do this with `win_command` with the right setting, but I wasn't able to figure it out.